# Scala - root of covariant type hierarchy

Tags: generics, scala, root, class-hierarchy, covariant

The following Scala class:

```
class Foo[+T <: Bar] extends FooBase ...
```

effectively defines a type hierarchy which has Foo[Bar] as its root - i.e. any valid Foo[X] will be assignable to a Foo[Bar] value or variable:

```
val v1: Foo[Bar] = new Foo[SubBar1]();
val v2: Foo[Bar] = new Foo[SubBar2]();
```

FooBase is further up and could also imply objects that are not Foo - the following shows the issue:

```
class Trouble extends FooBase ...
val iOnlyWantFooHere: FooBase = new Trouble();
```

... and also FooBase is not aware of type T, so its members cannot specify it and I'd have to override these definitions in Foo to specialize them:

```
class FooBase {
  def ohNoIDontKnowTheType: Bar;
}

class Foo[+T <: Bar] extends FooBase {
  override def ohNoIDontKnowTheType: T = ...;
}
```

There are other ways to work around that issue, but the point should be clear.

Finally, my actual question is what is the root of the following hierarchy:

```
class Foo[+T <: Foo[T]] extends FooBase ...
```

Again, do not tell me FooBase, because that is not the case. Yes, I could insert another class in between specifically for the purpose, but that is still not a true answer as indicated above.

Scala does not like just `Foo` (without the type parameter), and it is not `Foo[_]` either as then accessing methods returning the value of the type parameter type will actually be `Any`, not `Foo`. Of course, we cannot do `Foo[Foo]` either since that is also missing the type parameter for the second one and `Foo[Foo[_]]` or `Foo[Foo[Foo[Foo[_]]]` only gets us so many levels.

Is there an answer at all or does Scala lack support for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can omit the semi-colons; you can also omit empty parenthesis of constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `Foo[_ <: Foo[_]]`? Which, by the way, I did mention in my answer to your other question. Or you could write it like this:

```
type Base = Foo[t] forSome { type t <: Foo[t] }
```

Comment: Well, I missed that one there. I apologize. This is a good answer I was hoping for. Thanks!